# crontab working for one python script but not the other, why?

Tags: python, cron, macos-catalina

After a bit of frustration I've managed to run a test.py script from a tutorial I followed.

Works a treat but when I try my own script trending.py it does nothing

both scripts work from Atom like a dream
but trending.py just doesn't execute from crontab

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python ~/code/trending.py
* * * * * /usr/bin/python ~/code/test.py
```

does the contents of the script effect whether crontab with allow it to run?

using late 2013 iMac OS Catalina v.10.15.7 (incase that make a difference)

Comment: please include the permissions on them `ls -lhaF` (omit username if you like)

Comment: Redirect stdout and stderr to a file so you can see why it's not running. Add `>> ~/cron.out 2>&1` to the end of the line.

Comment: i've done this and taken the test.py cronjob of the list so now I'm only trying to run trending.py. I can see that the cron.out file is updating every minute but how do I view the contents of a cron.out file